# Can feTurbulence in an SVG Filter be Rotated?

Tags: d3.js, svg, svg-filters

I have an SVG `<filter>` that uses `<feTurbulence>` to create a texture like so:

[image: image with vertical texture]

I create a vertical texture like this by using a large X base frequency and a smaller Y frequency within `<feTurbulence>`.  And I can do the same trick in reverse to get a horizontal texture.  But I'd really like to be able to create a diagonal texture, like this:

[image]

but I can't figure out how to rotate the output of `<feTurbulence>` within a filter.

I have considered a rather awkward workaround:  I could create an image larger than my target image, fill it with vertical texture, rotate the image to my desired angle, and then clip it to fit within my target image.  But I'm sure hoping there's a more straightforward way to do this!

Edit:  By request, the vertical texture filter (in d3.js code, but it should be obvious).  This is adapted from the film grain filter in Inkscape:

```
    filter = mapParams.defs
    .append('filter')
    .attr('x', '0%')
    .attr('y', '0%')
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .attr('filterUnits', 'objectBoundingBox')
    .attr('id', 'TreeTexture');
filter.append('feTurbulence')
        .attr('type', 'fractalNoise')
        .attr('baseFrequency', '1 0.1')
        .attr('numOctaves', '3')
    .attr('result','fpr1');
// De-saturate to B&W
filter.append('feColorMatrix')
    .attr('type', 'saturate')
    .attr('values','0.0')
    .attr('result', 'fpr2')
    .attr('in','fpr1');
filter.append('feComposite')
    .attr('operator', 'arithmetic')
    .attr('in','SourceGraphic')
    .attr('in2','fpr2')
    .attr('k1', '0')
    .attr('k2', '1')
    .attr('k3', '1.5')
    .attr('k4', '-0.4')
    .attr('result', 'fpr3');
filter.append('feColorMatrix')
    .attr('type', 'saturate')
    .attr('values','0.85')
    .attr('result', 'fpr4')
    .attr('in','fpr3');
filter.append('feBlend')
    .attr('mode', 'normal')
    .attr('in','fpr4')
    .attr('in2','SourceGraphic')
    .attr('result', 'fpr5');
filter.append('feComposite')
    .attr('operator', 'in')
    .attr('in','fpr5')
    .attr('in2','SourceGraphic')
    .attr('result', 'fpr6');
```

Edit:  To clarify (since it is relevant to the skew solution that Michael Mullany posted below), I want to apply this filter to an object with an arbitrary fill.  So it might be applied to a green object as shown here, but might also be applied to red object, etc.

Comment: Have you tried `.attr("transform", "rotate(45)")` on the final selection?

Comment: @pmkro:  transform does nothing on the `<feTurbulence>` or on the `<filter>`.  If I put it on the filled object itself, the whole object will rotate and not just the texture.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I found some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feTurbulence) around this. Maybe try the `direction` attribute.

Comment: @pmkro: The `direction` attribute doesn't do anything on either `feTurbulence` or `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate things using a displacement map, but it's pretty hard to reverse engineer the displacement map you need. You *can* skew things pretty easily. The results in either case are not super great, but it's possible.

If you're using a filter for some other reason, I would recommend that you create the texture you want in one SVG and reference it via feImage from your main doc. If you don't need a filter - just use it as a regular image fill.

But for fun - here's how you skew stuff inside a filter. As a shortcut I use a direct object references to pull the gradiented object into the main filter - but for cross-browser (aka firefox) support - you'd need to make this a separate SVG and inline it as a data URI

```html
<svg height="400px" width="400px" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
  <defs> 
    <linearGradient id="disred" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="texture" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="1 0.1" numOctaves="3"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                           0 1 0 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 1 0" result="texture2"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#redDisplace"/>
      <feDisplacementMap in="texture2" scale="-60" xChannelSelector="R"/>
      <feOffset dy="-60" dx="0"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      
    </filter>
    
      <rect id="redDisplace" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#disred)"/>
    
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" filter="url(#texture)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, I learned a lot from figuring out what was going on.  The problem with this answer is that if I want to apply the filter to an arbitrary object, the skew is a problem -- you really need to have a bigger fill that you can skew and then displace back and still be as big as the object to be filled.  But maybe I can figure out how to use this for my needs.  (I'll mark this as the best solution if I don't see something better in the next few days.)